# How to access attribute from a trained estimator in TransformedTargetRegressor pipeline in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I setup a small pipeline with scikit-Learn that I wrapped in a `TransforedTargetRegressor` object. After the training, I would like to access the attribute from my trained estimator (e.g. `feature_importances_`). Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

# setup the pipeline
Pipeline(steps = [('scale', StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True)),
                  ('estimator', RandomForestRegressor())])

# tranform target variable
model = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipeline, 
                                   transformer=MinMaxScaler())
           
# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I tried the following:

```
# try to access the attribute of the fitted estimator
model.get_params()['regressor__estimator'].feature_importances_
model.regressor.named_steps['estimator'].feature_importances_
```

But this results in the following `NotFittedError`:

> NotFittedError: This RandomForestRegressor instance is not fitted yet.
> Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into the documentation of [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) it says that the attribute `.regressor_` (note the trailing underscore) returns the **fitted** regressor. Hence, your call should look like:

```
model.regressor_.named_steps['estimator'].feature_importances_
```

Your previous calls were just returning an unfitted clone. That's were the error came from.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! the code snippet you proposed returned a "TypeError: 'Pipeline' object is not subscriptable". However, based on your answer I figured out, that "model.regressor_.named_steps['estimator'].feature_importances_" works!

Comment: Does anyone know why they used a trailing underscore here? Is there some convention about naming?